# pandasの dataframeに列を追加し、リストの要素をセットする方法を教えてください

Tags: pandas

以下のソースのようにpandasでdataframeを作りました。
一番下の行のコードで、「Ｃ列を追加し１行目にリストをセット」したいです。
しかし、エラーが出ます。
理由が分かりませんでした。
どうすれば回避できるでしょうか？
下から２行目のコードで「Ａ列１行目にリストをセット」は出来たのですが。。。

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns={'A', 'B'})
df2.at[0, 'A'] =['a','b']
df2.at[0, 'C'] = ['c','d']
```

Comment: `df2.at[0, 'C'] = [['c'], ['d']]` という方法もあります。

Comment: metropolis様　いつもご回答、ご指導ありがとうございます。この書き方がありましたかぁ。atの書式をもう少し突っ込んで調べてみます。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`at`では存在しない行・列は指定出来ないようですので、</del>いったん新しい列を追加する処理をはさめば良いでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns={'A', 'B'})
df2.at[0, 'A'] =['a','b']
df2['C'] = None  # 新しい列を追加する処理をはさむ
df2.at[0, 'C'] = ['c','d']
```

Comment: kunif様　いつもご回答、ご指導ありがとうございます。
「atでは存在しない行・列は指定出来ない」ということを当方知りませんでした。やはり私の知識は浅いと痛感しております。kunif様はこのことをどこで得られたのでしょうか？普段からpandasの英語の取説を熟読されているのでしょうか？

Comment: 短いプログラムなので、実際に動かして色々試しています。しかし、@metropolis さんがコメントに書かれたようにやったら出来たので、「atで出来ない」というのは間違いのようです。私の方はもう一つ別のやり方ということになりますね。プログラミングにはそこそこ慣れていて、ちょっとしたことを調べたり試したりは出来ますが、仕様を熟知しているわけでは無いので、こういうこともよく発生します。