# データフレームの１要素にseriesを入れるときの扱い方

Tags: python

実行環境:
Python 3.8.8
OpenCV 4.5.3
です。
イメージとしては、

```py
ser00 = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0], index=['a','b', 'c','d'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key0', 'x0', 'x1', 'ser00'])
s = pd.Series(['K0', 1, 2, ser00], index=df.columns )
df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
```

という感じのを作って、下記のようなことをやりたいです。

1. １行丸ごと書き換え
   イメージ：df.loc["key0",:] = [0, 1, 2, [0, 0, 0, 0] ]
   や、
2. dfの４番目の要素で、
   a)  特定の場所（'a'の部分だけ、など）に値を入れる
   b)  ser00の部分のみを丸ごと書き換え

というような感じのことをしたのですが、どうしたらよいのでしょうか？
ちなみに、１では、

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested
> sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
> with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do
> this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
> return asarray(a).ndim

というのが出ています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 1については warning message にある通りに対応すれば良いでしょう。 `df.loc[df.key0=='K0'] = np.array([0, 1, 2, [[0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=object)` 参考:[pandasの dataframeに列を追加し、リストの要素をセットする方法を教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60562)]

Comment: ありがとうございました。 'dtype=object' なんとかについては、どういうソースコードを描くのか意味が理解できていませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

質問の(Python 3.8.8 の)当時は `df.append`が存在したようですが, (この回答で示す)現在の pandasでは使えません。もしくは append非推奨

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'2.1.4'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key0', 'x0', 'x1', 'ser00'])
>>> df.append
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6204, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?
```

---

現状での追加の方法と, 修正の方法を示します
(colabでの動作 … colabでも, そのうち append使えなくなるという警告が出ます)

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
# 1.5.3

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key0', 'x0', 'x1', 'ser00'])
ser00 = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
s = pd.Series(['K0', 1, 2, ser00], index=df.columns)

# df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)   # (元のコード)

# pd.concat を使用する方法
df = pd.concat([df, s.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

# .loc 使う方法 (1)
df.loc[0] = s.values

# .loc 使う方法 (2)
df.set_index('key0', inplace=True)
df.loc[s.key0] = s.values[1:]
```

質問内の

> イメージ：df.loc["key0",:] = [0, 1, 2, [0, 0, 0, 0] ]

… の意味がよく伝わらないけど

- インデックスを利用したいのなら, 「`.loc` 使う方法 (2)」で
- インデックスを 0から始まる数値で利用するなら「`.loc` 使う方法 (1)」,
  もしくは `pd.concat()` で

行うと良いでしょう。
インデックスありだとキー値の変更にはもう少し手間がかかるので注意

---

変更を行う場合 (全体)

```py
# インデックス未使用の場合
df.loc[df.key0 == "K0",:] = ['K0', 1, 2, [0, 0, 0, 0]]

# インデックス使用時
df.loc["K0",:] = [1, 2, [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Seriesのみの置き換え (インデックス無しの場合)

```py
df.loc[df.key0 == "K0", 'ser00'] = ([1,2,3,4,5,6],)

# Seriesの一部の書き換え
s = df.loc[df.key0 == "K0", 'ser00']
print(type(s))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

s[0][2] *= 3
df.loc[df.key0 == "K0", 'ser00'] = s
# 0 K0  1   2   [1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6]
```

※ pandasは(どちらかというと？)カラム指向なので, 頻繁に行を追加する処理には向きません
(処理速度はかなり遅くなるでしょう。普通に(？)リストで持つほうが速い)
(老婆心ながら) 質問のコートからすると, 設計見直したほうが良いかも

Answer (score 0):

4行目でデータフレームdfにSeriesのsを追加してるけど、それは無理です。
なぜなら、dfはcolumnだけの行で、sはSeriesの列です。
appendで追加できるのは、行のみです。